# Array Object/Class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying a arrayObjects with respective instantiation.

I try put multiple objects in a array but I don't know correct sintax

I'm trying :

```
Class[] classes = new Class[]{ViewHolder1.class,ViewHolder2.class};
```

In my adapter have :

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
Class[] classes; // -> will get values
```

I can do :

```
viewHolder = new ViewHolder1(v1);
```

But I don't know how I can acces my object from array :

```
viewHolder = new classes[i](v1); //can't not find simbol class.
```

I don't know if need I Object[] // Class[], and how instantiate correct.

Comment: Please read some tutorial to get better understanding about java

Comment: My problem is I can not take an object [], because if you know that the "view" is initialized to "onCreateViewHolder" is nonsense, put objects, because the view of the object the call just when I'm creating onCreateViewHolder, not before, I need passar an array of "classes" and then these "classes" classes viewHolder = new [] (view) // this can not. I hope you understand. This is a problem of Android, but with the logic of java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i got from your comment is, you have an array of `Class` type objects and you want to instantiate `Object` of that `Class`

You can achieve it via [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html), so if it is about 0th element in your class array you will have to do it like this:

```
Constructor ctor = classes[0].getDeclaredConstructor(<Class of v1 Object>);
ctor.setAccessible(true);

viewHolder = ctor.newInstance(v1);
```

This code is just to give you an idea about how reflection can be used. You need to adjust it to make it fully functional.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The best solution I've found for now, really seems good, (<Class of v1 Object>);  "v1 is a view", How I can pass a view into getDeclaredConstructor ?

Comment: You will pass `View.class`

Comment: Great you are awesome !

Comment: My last question How I can do it with "ViewHolder1 vh1 = (ViewHolder1) viewHolder;"  with reflection ?

Comment: for this why do you need to use reflection you straight forward do it

Comment: Seems correct, but I don't know how I can cast and how do "ViewHolder1/2 vh1 = (ViewHolder1/2) viewHolder, after I don't know how I can get vh1.setmethod11("a"), vh1.getmethod22("b")

Comment: I'm now onBindViewHolder, I from recycle view  , https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView, I need multiples object and multiples methods with reflection ... , I only need last step, so crazy

Comment: Kindly create a new question with specific details. Thanks